# Como que eu faço algum comando pra ir de um painel de opcao pra outro no python

Tags: python

Tipo eu tava fazendo um negocio q tinha um painel de opçoes que vc escolhe o numero e ai ele vai e executa tipo

```
Fazer oque:
1: ir ao mercado
2: ficar em casa
1 (pra ir ao mercado)
```

dai depois que eu escolhi ir no mercado

```
Você foi ao mercado com 5 reais no bolso.
1: comprar algo
2: voltar pra casa
2
#comando pra voltar pra casa é executado
```

como faço o comando pra voltar pra casa, e dai executar tudo as opçoes de casa e etc de novo? tem como? 
(eu sou novo no python entao digam de um jeito que eu entenda)

Código:

```
    # INICIO DO GAME
import time

time.sleep(3)
dinheiro = 5
acao1 = int(input('\nVocê está em casa. Escolha oque fazer: '
                  '\n1: Ir ao mercado '
                  '\n2: Dispensar o personal trainer e terminar '
                  '\n3: Praticar exercícios'
                  '\n4: Ir ao trabalho\n'))
if acao1 == 1:
    acao_mercado = int(input(
        'Você foi ao mercado com {0} reais no bolso'
        '\n1: Comprar algo'
        '\n2: Voltar pra casa'
        '\n'.format(str(dinheiro))))
    if acao_mercado == 1:
        acao_compra = int(input('Você foi ver oque tem para comprar'
              '\nVai comprar oque?'
              '\n1: Ovo R$2'
              '\n2: Leite R$3'
              '\n3: Banana R$1'
              '\n4: Trigo 1kg R$3'
              '\n5: Margarina R$5'
              '\n6: Açucar 1kg R$3'
              '\n7: Sair do mercado'))
        if acao_compra == 1 and dinheiro >= 2:
            dinheiro = dinheiro - 2
            print('Você comprou um ovo por 2 reais')
            #comando pra voltar pra compra de coisas
        if acao_compra == 2 and dinheiro >= 3:
            dinheiro = dinheiro - 3
            print('Você comprou um leite por 3 reais')
            # comando pra voltar pra compra de coisas
        if acao_compra == 3 and dinheiro >= 1:
            dinheiro = dinheiro - 1
            print('Você comprou uma banana por 1 real')
            # comando pra voltar pra compra de coisas
        if acao_compra == 4 and dinheiro >= 3:
            dinheiro = dinheiro - 3
            print('Você comprou um pacote de trigo por 3 reais')
            # comando pra voltar pra compra de coisas
        if acao_compra == 5 and dinheiro >= 5:
            dinheiro = dinheiro - 5
            print('Você comprou uma margarina por 5 reais')
            # comando pra voltar pra compra de coisas
        if acao_compra == 6 and dinheiro >= 3:
            dinheiro = dinheiro - 3
            print('Você ocmprou um pacote de açucar por 3 reais')
            # comando pra voltar pra compra de coisas
        if acao_compra == 7:
            #comando pra sair do mercado
    #if acao_mercado == 2:
        #comando para voltar pra casa
```

Comment: Como você está implementando isso, é através de funções? Se for, você pode simplesmente dar um 'return' para sair da função atual e voltar para a função anterior.

Comment: eu fiz só o codigo pra ir no mercado, daí olhar oque tem pra comprar, e pra comprar um ovo, dai ele tira 2 reais da variavel dinheiro. foi tudo feito com variaveis e if e print, nenhuma função (eu acho)

Comment: Poderia, por favor, editar a sua pergunta e inserir o código que você fez até agora? Assim nós conseguiremos te ajudar melhor.

Comment: pronto coloquei

Comment: Não coloque código como imagem. Não só fica dificil de ver num dispositivo movel, como não dá sequer para testar se digitar tudo de novo. Coloque sempre o código como texto formatando-o corretamente no editor da pergunta

Comment: pronto arrumei ele

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu escrevi um código bastante simples, só para poder te mostrar uma ideia de implementação utilizando funções.
Repare que estou utilizando o bloco *while* dentro das funções para ficar perguntando a opção e não sair logo da função. Você pode tentar implementar isso sem o *while* e ver o resultado (Sem o *while* o código só é executado uma vez).
Eu não coloquei nenhum tipo de verificação de segurança para capturar exceções caso o usuário insira uma letra ao invés de um número, é realmente bem simples.
O *main()* é a função principal do seu programa.

```
dinheiro = 5
# Função chamada quando você entra no mercado
def mercado():
    print('Você foi ao mercado com {} reais no bolso'.format(dinheiro))
    while True:
        acao = int(input('O que você deseja?\n'
        '1: Comprar algo\n'
        '2: Voltar para casa'))
        if acao == 1:
            ver_produtos()
        elif acao == 2:
            return   # Aqui volta para a função anterior.
# Esta função mostra os produtos que você pode comprar
def ver_produtos():
    while True:
        acao = int(input('O que quer comprar?\n'
        '1: Ovo R$2\n'
        'Pode colocar outros produtos aqui...\n'
        '7: Sair do mercado'))
        if acao == 1:
            print('Implemente isso aqui')
        elif acao == 7:
            return   # Volta para a função do mercado.
        else:
            print('Esse produto está em falta!')
# Função chamada na opção 3 do menu principal.
def exercitar():
    print('Você fez vários exercícios!')
# Esta é a função do menu principal do programa.
def main():
    while True:
        acao = int(input('Você está em casa, o que deseja fazer?\n'
        '1: Ir ao mercado\n'
        '2: Sair\n'
        '3: Praticar exercícios\n'))
        if acao == 1:
            mercado()   # Vai para a função do mercado.
        elif acao == 2:
            break   # Sai do while
        elif acao == 3:
            exercitar()   # Faz os exercicios.
    print('Até a próxima!')   # Cai aqui quando sai do while.
# Chama a função principal do seu programa.
main()
```

Dê uma olhada nesse código, acho que você conseguirá implementar o que deseja a partir disso.
Espero ter te ajudado! :D

Comment: pra que serve o "while True: depois dos def? Entendi tudo menos isso.

Comment: Serve pra ficar em repetição, como você está aprendendo, vale a pena dar uma olhada aqui: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LH6OIn2lBaI

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer algo assim:

```js
dinheiro = 10
a = int(input("digite sua opcao aqui: "))# nessa linha voce captura a opcaoo do usuario garante que a variavel sera do tipo int e exibe na tela o texto entre aspas.
if(a==1):
  dinheiro=dinheiro-5 # aqui armazena o valor na sua variavel dinheiro você tambem pode fazer dinheiro -= 5 que faz a mesma coisa escolha um que prefira
  print("-5")
elif():
  print("opcao 2 ")
elif():
  print("opcao 3")
else:
  print("opcao invalida")

b = int(input("outra escolha:"))
if(b==2):
 print(dinheiro)
```

Comment: sim eu fiz isso, mas só serve pra ir, por exemplo opção 1 : entrar no mercado, ok selecionei ela, agora eu estou no mercado mas e se eu quiser sair do mercado, voltar la onde estava a opcao 1 entrar no mercado